# Do objects drawn by Flash Graphics class exist as objects?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Internally Flash obviously keeps a list of the primitives drawn using `Graphics` so I wondered if you have many such primitives in a `Sprite`, can you re-position/remove/alter individual items rather than clear and re-draw everything? Or is this deeper into the bowels of Flash than you're allowed (or recommended) to go?

Comment: Possibly it *doesn't* keep track of primitives, and draws directly to a buffer somewhere (this would be faster to redraw when nothing has changed)...

Comment: @Cameron that wouldn't make sense for vector graphics since you can scale and move objects, etc?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but I thought that when you use the Graphics object it doesn't redraw the primitives when you scale the Sprite (only stretches them, etc)

Comment: @Cameron my understanding was it stretches them _as_ vector graphics hence no jagged pixels. That implies they are redrawn as needed, so some 'object' describing the shape is stored somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible: Once the items are drawn, you can only modify the full shape, but not the drawing itself.

To give you more of an explanation, I googled about how Flash actually calculates display objects. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything specific.

But I found enough to make an educated guess: **[EDIT]: I found a very interesting PDF on the [Anatomy of a Flash](http://corlan.org/downloads/flashcampbucharest/Flash-Anatomy.pdf).  It explains the rendering tree and how graphics objects are treated internally.**

I know for a fact that all shape tweens created in the IDE are compiled into shape sequences (each frame is stored as a separate image).  And it makes sense to do it that way: Each new frame of the movie must be calculated, all vector images are added to a tree, each rendered as bitmaps, combined and drawn as one final bit plane, in order to be displayed.  So it is only logical to do every possible shape *calculation* at compile time, rather than at runtime.

Then again, a bitmap would store 32 bits of color information for every single pixel, while vectors are stored in simple values, storing x and y coordinates, line style, fill style, etc. Some vectors can be grouped, so that for more complex shapes, line and fill styles only have to be stored once, and only coordinates are necessary for the rest. Also, primitive shapes like circles and rectangles require less information than objects combined from many individual points and lines.

**[EDIT]: The above mentioned PDF says this:**

> Both AS3 and AS3 DisplayObjects are
>   converted to SObjects internally. 
>   SObjects have a character associated. 
>   Based on the character type it has
>   different drawing methods, but it all
>   resumes to drawing fills with
>   different source of colors.

It would take a very, very complex vector shape to require more single pieces of information than its bitmap representation, provided it is larger than a few pixels in width and height.  Therefore, keeping simple shapes as vector representations consumes considerably less memory than storing full bitmaps - and so it is logical not to do shape *rendering* at compile time, as well (except for complicated shapes - then the "cacheAsBitmap" property comes into play).

Consider what I've said about vectors, line style and fill style, etc. - sounds quite a lot like the sequence of commands we have to write when drawing in ActionScript, right?  I would assume these commands are simply converted 1:1 into exactly the kind of vector representations I was talking about. This would make the compiler faster, the binaries smaller, and the handling of both the IDE shapes and the AS shapes exactly the same.

**[EDIT]: Turns out I was not quite right on that:**

> Edge & Colors
>
> - LSObjects tree is traversed and a list of edges is created
>
>   - Edges have colors associated
>   - Strokes are converted to edges
>   - Colors are sources of display data, eg. Bitmaps, Video, Solid fills,
>       Gradients
> - Rasterization
>
>   - Edges are sorted and a color is calculated for each pixel – pixels are
>       touched only once
> - Presentation
>
>   - After the main rasterizer is done painting, the memory buffer is
>       copied to the screen

Now imagine all of those vectors were freely editable:
**The sequence of commands would no longer be final!**  What if you were to add, move or erase one at runtime?  For example: Having a rectangle inside of a filled rectangle subtracts the inner shape from the outer shape.  What if you moved one of the corner points to the outside? The result would be a completely different shape!  Or if you added one point?  You could not store the shape as a rectangle any longer, requiring 5 point items to draw the same thing that once had been one rect item.  In short: All the groupings and memory optimizations would no longer work.  And it would also slow down runtime graphics considerably.  That's why it is only allowed to add new elements to the shape, but not to modify them once they are drawn.  And why you have to clear and redraw your graphics, if you want existing shapes to change.

**[EDIT]: You can always do complex stuff by doing the calculations yourself. I still believe it was a good decision not to integrate those into basic graphics functionality.**

Comment: I also would like to see why - it's a nice long answer that appears to have taken some time. Be polite and explain why it's not useful please.

Comment: I found something more concrete.  Edited the answer.

Comment: weltraumprat, I downvoted your comment because you were jumping down a rabbit hole of technically incorrect assumptions, but as you've been editing it to provide accurate info I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: @seanalltogether: Thanks, both for answering and reversing your vote. - I can live with criticism, as long as it offers some advice on how to improve. And I actually have to thank you again: I probably wouldn't have searched any longer if it hadn't been for that down vote ;)

Answer (score 4):

Drawing primitives aren't accessible to user code once they've been committed to the graphics context, but if you need fast drawing objects you should use shapes instead of sprites. Sprites are containers that can contain other sprites and graphics contexts, Shapes are objects with only graphics contexts and non interactive.

```
Sprite -> DisplayObjectContainer - > InteractiveObject -> DisplayObject
Shape -> DisplayObject
```

Answer (score 1):

With Flash CS5, and the XFL file format, this data is now accessible as XML.

For my example, you could make a tile map composed of 'Graphic' items from a MovieClip with various frames being various tiles.  Instantly you come to the problem of needing to access those inaccessible frame indexes from 'Shape' objects.

If you put them into a symbol (even one that is not exported), you can find it in a file in your LIBRARY folder (after saving as 'xfl').  It mirrors the Library contents.

```
   <DOMSymbolItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfl/2008/" name="Tileset_Level_Test" itemID="4e00fe7f-00000450" linkageExportForAS="true" linkageClassName="Tileset_Level_Test" sourceLibraryItemHRef="Symbol 1" lastModified="1308719656" lastUniqueIdentifier="3">
  <timeline>
    <DOMTimeline name="Tileset_Level_Test">
      <layers>
        <DOMLayer name="Layer 1" color="#4FFF4F" current="true" isSelected="true" autoNamed="false">
          <frames>
            <DOMFrame index="0" keyMode="9728">
              <elements>
                <DOMSymbolInstance libraryItemName="Tileset_Test" name="" symbolType="graphic" firstFrame="8" loop="play once">
                  <transformationPoint>
                    <Point/>
                  </transformationPoint>
                </DOMSymbolInstance>
                <DOMSymbolInstance libraryItemName="Tileset_Test" name="" symbolType="graphic" firstFrame="4" loop="play once">
                  <matrix>
                    <Matrix tx="48"/>
                  </matrix>
                  <transformationPoint>
                    <Point/>
                  </transformationPoint>
                </DOMSymbolInstance>
... lots more...
              </elements>
            </DOMFrame>
          </frames>
        </DOMLayer>
      </layers>
    </DOMTimeline>
  </timeline>
</DOMSymbolItem>
```

The XML looks quite complex, but you can process it down to something much simpler with the XML class, and (for instance) construct a collision mask from a MovieClip mirroring those frame indexes, and identify spawn points and other special classes of things.  Or you might process the data and draw the whole map yourself, having only needed a way to build it visually.  All you might really care about is tx,ty attributes in the Matrix (for where a tile is placed), and 'firstFrame' attribute in the 'DOMSymbolInstance' (for which tile).

Anyways, you could preprocess it with an AIR applet to make just the data you want, and then either poop out a .as file to include in the project, or simplified XML, or whatever you like.  Or use whatever other tools/languages you prefer, and add that processing step to your build scripting.

The xfl file format is also handy for tracking down and fixing all manner of things which Flash is too broken/buggy/AFU to fix, such as leftover font references in obscure parts of parts of parts....  You can either fix them in the library, or literally delete the file of the offending part, or edit the XML by hand.  Grep and sed and find and xargs are all your friends for these tasks.  Especially for things like snapping all coordinates to integer values, or proper cell boundaries, since all of Flash 'snapping' is horribly broken, too.  Piping XML files through sed can be quite hazardous to files that you have not backed up, but quite rewarding for evil people who know what they're up to, and use version control.

Answer (score 0):

Well every DisplayObject has only one graphic reference. So if you want to move (or scale etc.) several graphic objects in one Sprite, I suggest you use the display tree as it was intended. 
Just add several children (Sprites or MovieClips or ...) in one Sprite each being redrawn when necessary.

Comment: Isn't that adding overhead if I have a `Sprite` for every primitive (rectangle/circle) - especially _creating_ & destroying new objects every frame?

Comment: Well depending on how much you want to move and scale things around. Since Flash (mainly FXG) caches most of the stuff that doesn't need to be redrawn it won't matter if you add lots of Sprites. Of course you could always keep track of what you want to draw yourself and actually redraw the graphic of you sprite each frame much like you would do in HTML5 Canvas.